# I cannot remove a pull request on github

Tags: github

[image: This is the page when I click on pull requests]

I have a pull request showing on Github and a button which says compare and pull request then when I click on it it says There isn't anything to compare, master and other-branch are identical. It also says there are no changed files.

If I click on pull requests in the header bar then I still get the same yellow box saying compare and pull request above the box with the actual pull requests in but within that box it says I have 0 open pull requests and 2 closed pull requests from a year ago.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: I'll attempt to help but I need a bit more information. When you say you have a PR showing, can you provide a link to the exact GitHub repo and PR. Second, I'm not sure what you mean by header bar. Perhaps a screenshot may be helpful in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I hope the screenshot above helps.

Comment: That normally pops up when there's are commits, so my question then is your new branch. Is it based off the main one? If not, then it won't be able to merge because there's no parent commit to identify how the branching occur.